# How to add HTTPS to Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-elb, amazon-web-services

I'm using **boto** to create an Apache **http server** that "hides" behind an AWS **Elastic Load Balancer** (ELB).
However, the ELB DNS address is functional only when I specify **port 80 (http)** in its security group. As soon as I add **port 443 (https)**, I cannot get to content served by the Apache server.

Can anyone point to documentation/examples on ***how to add support for HTTPS to ELB?***
(bonus points for information on how to use **self signed SSL certificates**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the AWS documentaion for setting up HTTPS/SSL Load Balancer:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SettingUpLoadBalancerHTTPS.html